# Android: Disabling the context menu for ActionBar items in ActionMode?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, listener

I made a multi-choice action mode in my ListFragment. It adds some new MenuItems on the ActionBar and it works great. **But I can't figure out, how and why does any long-click on my menuitems trigger a little, completely empty context menu?**

I tried to setEnable(false) and setVisibility(false) on it, but it's not helping at all - I just want to disable the context menu when long-pressing.